# Lista desordenada (UL) visualmente em lista vertical

Tags: html

Como  fazer com que os filhos de `UL` fiquem,visualmente , em uma lista vertical, no mesmo nível - ser ter que usar margem negativa-.?

```css
  #hamburguer {
  display: none;
}

#categ_menu {
  display: none;
}

.menu_nav {
  background-color: yellow;
}



#hamburguer:checked~.menu_nav {
  display: block;
}

.um_lider a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.um_lider li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 20px;
}

.um_lider ul {
  display: none;
  color: firebrick;
}

#categ_menu:checked~.ul_categ {
  display: block;
}

.um_lider li ul li a {}

.ul_categ {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.ul_categ>li {
  float: none;
  padding: 20px;
  background: red;
}

.itens::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: block;
```

```html
<nav class="menu_nav">
  <ul class="um_lider">

    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="categ_menu">
      <label for="categ_menu"> <a>categoria</a> </label>
      <ul class="ul_categ">
        <li><a href="#">Infantil</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Drama</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Amor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ação</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Crime</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Terror</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Suspense</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Aventura</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Policial</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Jogos</a></li>

      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">Fale Conosco</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CDs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Histórico</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sua conta</a></li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Nada, por padrão qualquer lista é exibida na vertical, se está na horizontal é porque fez algo. Seu código tem uma `<ul>` dentro de uma `<li>`, isso parece semanticamente estranho, de uma estudada em web semântica

Comment: Pensar em usar margem negativa é sinal ou de gambeta ou de que está se aventurando em HTML/CSS. É como o @Costamilam falou: uma lista já é vertical por padrão, e creio que não há problema de semântica em colocar uma `ul` dentro de uma `li`. O problema é que a sua pergunta está muito vaga.

Answer (score 1):

Basta você resetar o padding da sua `ul` assim:

```css
.um_lider {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```css
  #hamburguer {
  display: none;
}

#categ_menu {
  display: none;
}

.menu_nav {
  background-color: yellow;
}



#hamburguer:checked~.menu_nav {
  display: block;
}

.um_lider {
  padding: 0;
}

.um_lider a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.um_lider li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 20px;
}

.um_lider ul {
  display: none;
  color: firebrick;
}

#categ_menu:checked~.ul_categ {
  display: block;
}

.um_lider li ul li a {}

.ul_categ {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.ul_categ>li {
  float: none;
  padding: 20px;
  background: red;
}

.itens::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: block;
```

```html
<nav class="menu_nav">
  <ul class="um_lider">

    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="categ_menu">
      <label for="categ_menu"> <a>categoria</a> </label>
      <ul class="ul_categ">
        <li><a href="#">Infantil</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Drama</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Amor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ação</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Crime</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Terror</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Suspense</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Aventura</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Policial</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Jogos</a></li>

      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">Fale Conosco</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CDs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Histórico</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sua conta</a></li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Acho que eu entendi sua pergunta ai talvez seja o caso de vc mudar essa parte aqui

```
.ul_categ> li {
    float: none;
    padding: 20px;
    background: red;
}
```

Vc muda o padding para

```
padding: 20px 0;
```